# Calculate the number of days in stock from supplies and sales

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have two summary tables. `Supplies` contains the number of received products and `Sales` the number of total sales. I need to find out how many days the product was (not) in stock. E.g. for the period from `10.10.2017` to `1.5.2018` the product `666` was (not) in stock for `193 (11)` of the total 204 days. I would like to show some query, but I really don't know where to start. Expected result should be something like this.

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|        Period         | ProductID | Days in stock | Days total |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2017-10-10 - 2018-5-1 |       666 |           193 |        204 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Supplies**

```
+--------------+-----------+----------+
| DeliveryDate | ProductID | Quantity |
+--------------+-----------+----------+
| 2018-07-27   |       666 |       20 |
| 2018-05-04   |       666 |       10 |
| 2018-04-20   |       666 |        1 |
| 2017-07-29   |       666 |       10 |
+--------------+-----------+----------+
```

**Sales**

```
+-------------+-----------+----------+
| SummaryDate | ProductID | Quantity |
+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 2018-07-21  |       666 |        4 |
| 2018-07-14  |       666 |        4 |
| 2018-04-20  |       666 |       11 |
+-------------+-----------+----------+
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3151d)**

Comment: Provide sample data is very good, but Could you provide some expect result?

Comment: @D-Shih Updated the question, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You need some steps: Get in and out values in one column. If on the same day, add them up. Then build a running total. Then detect when and how long stock was zero. At last get the total of days without stock:

```
with in_and_out as
(
  select date, productid, sum(quantity) as quantity
  from
  (
    select deliverydate as date, productid, quantity from supplies
    union all
    select summarydate as date, productid, -quantity as quantity from sales
  ) in_and_out_raw
  group by date, productid
)
, running_totals as
(
  select date, productid, quantity, sum(quantity) over (partition by productid order by date) as total
  from in_and_out
)
, gaps_detected as
(
  select
    productid,
    case when total <= 0 then datediff(day, date, lead(date) over (partition by (productid) order by date)) end as diff
  from running_totals
)
select productid, sum(diff)
from gaps_detected
group by productid
order by productid;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3151d/21

Comment: Thanks for driving me in the right direction, I'm still trying to adjust it for the specified period, which is not as easy as it may seem.

Answer (score 0):

Put them together, use some lag to get the running total stock

```
with CTE as
(
select DeliveryDate as TheDate,
       ProductID,
       Quantity
from Supplies
union all
select SummaryDate,
       ProductID,
       Quantity * (-1)
from sales
)

select t1.*, 
       Quantity + lag (Quantity) over (partition by ProductID order by TheDate) as Stock
from CTE t1
```

You should be able to manipulate this to show the info you need.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't know the `lag` function. However, I don't think this will work, `2018-04-20` should return `0` in `Stock` instead of `-10`.